# SQL Server 2000 SQL Profiler filters ignored

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-profiler

I am not able to filter events in my database.

When creating a trace, I specify a "Database Name" in the filters tab and add my database name, "pr200".

However, the profiler seems to ignore this information and keeps showing events from all databases.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter for dbid instead of dbname, seems there is a bug inside the profiler.

Use
    sp_helpdb 'db_name'
to find the dbid for a given database name.